# Check if Url refers to file or DIrectory. (HTTP)

Tags: java, android, file, url

How can I determine if an url is referring to a file or directory. the link http://example.com/test.txt should return that it is a file an http://example.com/dir/ is a directory

I know you can do this with the Uri class but this objects IsFile function only works with the file:/// scheme. And I am working with the http:// scheme. Any idea's?

Thanks

Comment: You mean serverside? In what language/framework?

Comment: JAVA android. I want to make an app which can display documents of any kind. I no this can be done through shouldOverRideURLLoading() in which I check for .PDF or .DOC etc.. I want  to no if there is any other way for that purpose. I mean will there be any other information in URL except the extensions??

Comment: I'm not a java/android guy. I added the right tags to your question so other people will pick it up...

Comment: Using URL.getPath() i can retrieve the path in the url. But again I ll have to put search condition for extensions. I think there is no other way we can determine if the url is file or directory.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why this question was left unanswered/neglected for a long time. I faced the same situation in server-side java (reckon it would be similar for Android flavour). The only input information is a URL to the resource and we need to tell if the resource is a directory or file. So here's my solution.

```
if ("file".equals(resourceUrl.getProtocol())
    && new File(resourceUrl.toURI()).isDirectory()) {
    // it's a directory
}
```

Hope this helps the next reader.

Note: please see @awwsmm comment. It was my assumption when provided the answer above. Basically, it doesn't make sense to test if a remote resource is a directory or anything. It is totally up to the site to decide what to return for each request.

Comment: Precisely. Or you could maybe check to see if the last element in the path has an extension?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Debosmit. That would be the most efficient way but quite unreliable imho. In *nix systems, and possibly Windows, ordinary files can exist without an extension.

Comment: Yep. Precisely what I was thinking when I wrote the comment. :p

Comment: OP specifically says this only works with `file://` and they're trying to work with `http://`

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because protocol would be http:// not file://.

```
 class TestURL{
   public static boolean isDirectory(URL resourceUrl){
     if ("file".equals(resourceUrl.getProtocol())
       && new File(resourceUrl.toURI()).isDirectory()) {
        true;
     }
     return false;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println(TestURL.isDirectory("http://example.com/mydir/"));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a directory `http://example.com/some/dir` will redirect to `http://example.com/some/dir/`, a file will not.

ie one can examine the http `Location` field in the HEAD response:

```
$ curl -I http://example.com/some/dir | grep Location
Location: http://example.com/some/dir/
```

Comment: I will not downvote this, but this will only be the case with some web servers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to download a file with HTTPS and there was occasions that server was misconfigured to redirect the request and thus would download only http data.

In my case I was able to "decide" whether the requested resource was file or not was inspecting "content type" / aka MIME type.

```
        String[] allowedMimeTypes = new String[] { "application/octet-stream", "image/gif",
            "text/css", "text/csv", "text/plain", "text/xml" };            
        URL website = new URL("https://localhost/public/" + file);
        HttpsURLConnection huc = (HttpsURLConnection) website
                .openConnection();
        if (!Arrays.asList(allowedMimeTypes).contains(huc.getContentType())) {
            throw new Exception("Not a file...");
        }
```

When the response contained `text/html;charset=utf-8` or similar I was able to determine that it was indeed not a file.

Also note that these MIME types are usually quite configurable on server side.